Makefile setup for custom source/output directories
Goal
Create a makefile that successfully compiles my program with the following constraints (I like a clean project root directory).

Output final binary to root project directory (or possibly a ./bin directory).
Maintain all source files inside ./src directory (*.cpp, *.h)
Makefile should sit inside root project directory
All object files should be output adjacent to their source files inside ./src

What I've tried
Thus far, I've only been able to create a makefile where all object files are output to the root project directory.
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
OUTPUT := main

$(OUTPUT): main.o util.o
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(OUTPUT) main.o util.o

main.o: main.cpp ./src/util.h
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c main.cpp

util.o: ./src/util.h ./src/util.cpp
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c ./src/util.cpp


You didn't really show us what you tried.  You only showed us what worked.  If you'd shown us what you tried that DIDN'T work we could explain why.  However, this will work:
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
OUTPUT := main

$(OUTPUT): src/main.o src/util.o
            $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^

src/main.o: src/main.cpp src/util.h
            $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

src/util.o: ./src/util.cpp ./src/util.h
            $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

The key is that make starts from the END (main) and works backwards.  So you have to tell it where you want the object files to end up, in the prerequisite list of main.
But, you don't even have to do all this because GNU Make already knows how to build object files in the same directory as source files.  This makefile is good enough:
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
OUTPUT := main

$(OUTPUT): src/main.o src/util.o
            $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^

src/main.o src/util.o: src/util.h


Usually, the simple, reusable and robust way is this below:
CXX := g++
OUTPUT := main_util
SRC := src
OBJ := obj
SRCS += $(SRC)/util.cpp \
        $(SRC)/main.cpp
OBJS += $(OBJ)/util.o \
        $(OBJ)/main.o
HEADER += -I $(SRC)
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11$(HEADERS)

$(OUTPUT):$(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(CXXFLAGS)
$(OBJ)/%.o:$(SRC)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $< $(CXXFLAGS)
clean:
    rm $(OBJS) $(OUTPUT)

You can re-use it to anywhere for your different projects simple or complex by simply adding more files into those defined variables.
Note:
$@: targets' filenames in your desired path
$^: all dependencies' filenames in your desired path
$<: the first dependency's filename

